# How to get a periodic time series at a fixed time across a DST boundary?

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

Python's [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) has the ability to provide regularly spaced time intervals using ([at least](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html)) the [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.date_range.html) function:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pytz, datetime
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> tzto = pytz.timezone("America/Toronto")
>>> oct17 = tzto.localize(datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 17, 8))
>>> #get every Friday from Oct 17 (a Friday) for 5 weeks...
>>> pp(pd.date_range(oct17, periods=5, freq="W-FRI").tolist())
[Timestamp('2014-10-17 08:00:00-0400', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-24 08:00:00-0400', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-31 08:00:00-0400', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-11-07 07:00:00-0500', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-11-14 07:00:00-0500', tz='America/Toronto')]
```

Unfortunately, the initial time is lost when the interval spans a DST change.  This can be seen above where the last two entries above have moved back to 7 am due to a scheduled DST change in Toronto on Nov 2, 2014.

How can the series be constructed to keep the time identical across the DST boundary? ie: In the above example it should be 8 am for every entry above, instead of shifting to 7 am after the DST jump.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, the starting datetime must be naive.  Localize the timezone **after** the series is generated by passing the `tz` keyword argument to `date_range()`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pytz, datetime
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> tzto = pytz.timezone("America/Toronto")
>>> oct17_naive = datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 17, 8, 0, 0)
>>> pp(pd.date_range(oct17_naive, periods=5, freq="W-FRI", tz=tzto).tolist())
[Timestamp('2014-10-17 08:00:00-0400', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-24 08:00:00-0400', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-31 08:00:00-0400', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-11-07 08:00:00-0500', tz='America/Toronto'),
 Timestamp('2014-11-14 08:00:00-0500', tz='America/Toronto')]
```

All times above are at 8 am, even across the DST jump on Nov 2.